# Does losing part of your body reduce the amount of Force power you can wield?

Tags: star-wars, the-force

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When Jedi lose parts of their body, does their midi-chlorian count and strength in the Force diminish?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4097/when-jedi-lose-parts-of-their-body-does-their-midi-chlorian-count-and-strength)

If the Force is a function of midi-chlorians in the blood, does that mean that as people lose part of their body (such as arms, legs, or lower torso) reduce their Force sensitivity?

- Anakin Skywalker lost his right arm (and ultimate both arms and legs), did that affect his ability to channel the Force?
- Luke Skywalker lost his lower arm (roughly 1.87% of his total body mass) did his Force power also diminish by that much?
- Darth Maul lost his entire lower body, which was replaced with robotics. Having lost essentially 50% of his midi-chlorians, is he 50% less Force sensitive?

What effect does losing body parts (and by the same token losing midi-chlorians) have on one's ability to control the Force?

Comment: Wait, Darth Maul survived? I only ever watched the first two.

Comment: @John Yes. Its featured in *Star Wars: The Clone Wars* TV series.