# Could General Grievous be a Sith?

Tags: star-wars, sith

Could General Grievous have been a Sith? Even though he had so many lightsabers from beating Jedi, was he capable enough to undergo Sith training?

Answer (score 13):

No.

[Grievous](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Grievous)'s biological part doesn't have midichlorians, so he can't use the *Force* at all whether dark side or not.

**Note:** Only *Force* sensitives can be Jedi or Sith.

Comment: kinda opens the question of if you can transplant midichlorians like a new liver

Comment: @severa This has been discussed here... Its not possible.

Comment: @SachinShekhar -  a link or better yet a quote confirming lack of midichlorians would be helpful

Comment: In one of the discussions earlier, it was mentioned that Grievious *did* have midichlorians in his blood from a blood transfusion from Sifo-Dyas, but it still didn't make him force-sensitive. So, yes - you *can* transplant midichlorians - it's just doesn't have the effect hoped for.

Comment: I thought midichlorians where in all living things, but force sensetives had a much higher content than the average individual.

Comment: @SachinShekhar (or anyone else): can you link that discussion? I don't know of canon references to midichlorian transfusions, but there are plenty of (pre-Disney) canon instances of artificial Force sensitivity.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's canon or fanon, but I think I read somewhere that midichlorians are a symptom of force-sensitivity but not the source. There is also the game Jedi Outcast where a technical method to give force abilities to previously force-insensitive people is a plot device, but it is historically much later than the clone wars, so the technology might not have existed back then.

Comment: @Fatbird3 In the Legends comic [The Eyes of Revolution](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Eyes_of_Revolution) we get detail of Grievous' body being rebuilt. The process includes a transfusion of midichlorian-rich blood from the body of Jedi Master Sifo Dyas, with the hope that the blood will make Grievous Force sensitive. It fails.

Answer (score 3):

According to '[Star Wars Graphics](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Graphics)' (A book of [dubious canonicity](https://twitter.com/PabloHidalgo/status/725023028732674048)<sup>1</sup>) General Grievous has 11,900 midichlorians, 100 fewer than Darth Maul, and more than

- Qui-gon Jinn (10,000)
- Shaak Ti (10,300)
- Ki-adi-mundi (10,600)
- Plo Kloon (11,100)
- Kit fisto (11,800)

So if all it takes to potentially be a Sith is force sensitivity, which is from midichlorians, then yes he has the potential. However he has lost most of his body, and while [opinion is divided](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/4097/3804) that's likely destroyed what potential he had.

If using the force (Force Lightning and other obvious effects) isn't too important, and we call Darth Maul (who is better known for Lightsaber combat) a Sith I still think he could live up to the name of being a Sith

<sub>1. "I don't know. I've never seen that! Looks neat." - Pablo Hidalgo</sub>

Comment: *mod hat* Please do not make changes to the answer that conflict with the original answerer's intention.

Comment: A previous edit says this book is non-cannon. Why would that be?

Answer (score 2):

General Greivous was more man than machine. Even if he was a little Force sensitive there wasn't a lot of natural body parts that would allow him to channel the Force. So to answer your question, no. If he was able to harness the Force however, he would need to be crafted strong Force drawn armor using Sith alchemy.

Comment: Should this read 'more machine than man', inferring from the following statement?

Answer (score 1):

Sith is a whole set of training and teachings. Gen. Grievous did not undergo Sith training and was not able to use the Force.

Answer (score 0):

I recall him using the Force; don't remember if it was at his space fleet or in Clone Wars series. Dooku may have asked him not to use the Force because he was breaking Rule of Two.

Comment: Welcome, are there any sources or scenes you could use to prove your comments, as far as other answers have indicated, Grievous never used the Force.

Answer (score -1):

I swear I saw Grievous use the force to push something away. Also wiki says all humans or beings have midi-chlorians. 2500. Anakin 20,000 per cell. We all have them light or dark. Training or not. Training helps the more sensitive to hone and control the Force. Grievous. Missing a lot of muscle. Would half his cells even if his remaining blood had 15,000 or what eves the total would make him less sensitive. A tall strong Jedi body builder. Would be as capable as Anakin. Just by total blood mass, even if he had lower per cell midi-chlorian count. Have to be rationally similar though. That I'll give You. Strong as obi wan. Midi-chlorians per cell count-wise. A man ch for Anakin easy.

Comment: What does "A man ch for Anakin easy." mean?

Comment: Can you provide a source for him using the Force? I'm certain he never did in anything canon.

Answer (score -1):

General Grievous could not use the force or be Sith because he was too mechanical and altered, reconstructed from droid parts. He did have Jedi Master Sifo-Dyas's blood (from his corpse) transferred into him-only to keep him from dying so there were midichlorians in the blood but they only keep him alive.
On the other hand, he does state that he had Lightsaber combat training, so half of what would be needed is there.

[Reference](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sifo-Dyas/Legends)

Comment: Can you provide sources for your answer?

Comment: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sifo-Dyas/Legends

Comment: Don't forget to [edit](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/104919/edit) them into the answer