# Why didn't Kenobi turn Grievous Lightsabers off?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber, revenge-of-the-sith, obi-wan-kenobi

As I read, Jedi learn early on to 'force shield' themselves so that another Jedi cannot turn their Lightsaber off during battle.

Is there a in-universe explanation as to why Obi-wan Kenobi didn't do that in *Revenge of the Sith* with Grievous Lightsabers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the Force requires you to gain mental focus, ideally by meditating, but in a pinch (such as during a fight) by simply concentrating quite hard. **By going on the offensive constantly, Grievous was able to rattle Kenobi sufficiently that he wasn't able to use his Force powers.** Note that as soon as Obi-Wan is able to get a little physical distance, he's able to use a Force push.

As to why, *specifically* he didn't just flip Grievous' lightsabers off, that would seem to require a level of concentration and precision that needs far more than a second or two of focus. Attempting such an intricate move in the middle of a fight would likely result in his immediate death, and that's assuming that Grievous doesn't just beat him to death with the handles.

> It was almost like fighting four different people at once. Obi-Wan’s
> lightsaber blurred as he blocked and parried, but he knew he couldn’t
> keep that up for long. Time for a different approach. He leaped,
> flipping high over Grievous to land behind him.
>
> Grievous didn’t have to turn; he just rotated his mechanical body
> until he faced the other way. But even doing that took time and threw
> off his attack, just enough to let Obi-Wan’s lightsaber swirl past his
> guard. Two of his four arms dropped to the floor, still gripping their
> stolen lightsabers.
>
> Before Grievous could adjust, and attack with his two remaining
> lightsabers, Obi-Wan reached for the Force. He lifted Grievous into
> the air, throwing him against one of the beams that supported the
> upper level. The impact shook the lightsabers out of his grasp. They
> landed on the floor of the control center, while Grievous slid past
> the edge of the floor and fell to the level below.
>
> [SW: Revenge of the Sith - Junior Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_III:_Revenge_of_the_Sith_(junior_novelization))

Answer (score -2):

In the films, grievous says:

> I've been trained in your Jedi arts by Count Dooku

So if it's so important, I'm assuming Dooku went through this on day one of training.

Comment: He may have been trained in the Jedi dueling arts, but as he was not Force Sensitive and more than half droid, I don't think he could use the Force shield

Comment: What source confirms he wasn't force sensitive?

Comment: It's explained here: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/42958/3804

Comment: Nothing is referenced in those answers, just conversational. There must be midichlorians in general grievous, Qui-Gon Jin says explicitly in Phantom that all living things have them. It is also implied that the concentrations of midichlorians are what dictate force-affinity, so the fact that grievous is mostly mechanical should not affect anything.

Comment: In what is now Legends canon, Grievous was given blood from Sify-Dyas, and it failed to give him any ability with the Force. See [Are Midi-chlorians able to be infused or transplanted?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/49586/5184)

Comment: In 'The Eyes of Revolution' (which is the referenced proof for the Wookiepedia article linked in that post), General Grievous says nothing of the force after his transformation. He destroys his droid guards in anger at a cutting comment from Count Dooku, and the story closes as he screams "I am not a droid! I am General Grievous!"