# Who had the highest midi-chlorian count before the birth of Anakin Skywalker?

Tags: star-wars, midichlorians

I'm interested to know which individual, **living or dead**, **Jedi or Sith**, had the highest midi-chlorian count prior to Anakin's birth. Anakin was known to have been the "highest" when he was discovered and tested by Qui-Gon at *more than 20,000 midi-chlorians*.

> QUI-GON : Make an analysis of this blood sample I'm sending you.
>
> QUI-GON : What are your readings?
>
> OBI-WAN : Strange. The transmission seems to be in good order, but the
> reading's off the chart...**over twenty thousand**.

This shows that they didn't expect the readings to be so high, clearly implying that Anakin had the highest midi-chlorian count ever seen.

**I've seen some [sites](http://www.killermovies.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-531325-midichlorian-counts.html) that give a table of the Jedi/Sith with the highest midi-chlorian count, but I can't seem to find a source for those tables.**

So who had the highest midi-chlorian count before the birth of Anakin Skywalker? Is there any such individual who was *stated or implied*?

Comment: The very next line is "Even Master Yoda doesn't have a count that high", so my guess would be Yoda.

Comment: @DisturbedNeo I completely agree with that statement, as it clearly shows, via Obi Wan's surprise, that they knew who had the highest count.

Comment: Those lists were invented by a fabulist called Supershadow. He specialised in inventing "script leaks" and interviews with George Lucas until LucasFilm sued him and got his site taken down; [What were the midi-chlorian counts for the main characters in the films?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/27942/what-were-the-midi-chlorian-counts-for-the-main-characters-in-the-films?rq=1)

Comment: The duplicates indicate what's known (canonically) about midi-chlorian counts, which is to say *next to nothing*.

Comment: I see, so that's literally no answer for this save the implication about Yoda @DisturbedNeo states..

Comment: @Voronwë if that is accepted, then it is again a dupe, as that is the same as the answer to another question.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/151663/68872

Comment: @Edlothiad that's not the accepted answer though, and our questions are completely different

Comment: The site policy is that if an answer on a question answers your question then we point to it as a duplicate. This is to prevent multiple answers of the same kind coming up on the site.

Comment: Whether or not the answer is accepted is irrelevant. Besides, the linked question doesn't even _have_ an accepted answer (Should probably ask that the OP does that). Anyway, the main thing we have to figure out is _can a better answer than the one in the linked question be provided for this question_. If the answer is yes, this question can stay open and an answer can be provided. If no, then this question should be closed as a dupe of the linked question.

Comment: In my opinion, a more direct answer can be provided, since the answer in the link doesn't actually imply that Yoda was the next highest after Vader, merely that Vader had a higher count than both Yoda and Obi-Wan. However, I don't believe that any answer to this question could provide any additional information, since there isn't any additional information from any canonical sources.

Comment: @Edlo Site policy: [*normally* the presence of identical answers is a pretty good indication that the questions themselves are the same (unless the answer is something trivial like the name of a character). But this doesn't hold if a question has managed to attract a lot of different answers - so you end up in situations where various answers might be applied to completely different questions even though most of the answers are inapplicable](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9748). It would be silly to close A as dupe of B just because B's sixth answer way down the page kind of solves A.

Comment: @Randal'Thor, sure say that, but then I invite you to go through all the dupes where we have done EXACTLY that. I have an issue with this whole "*site policy*" thing anyways. We should have somewhere where someone can actually go read exactly what is and isn't site policy instead of "It's on meta" or have a meta tag that defines which questions are "*site policy*"

Comment: Second answer 37 upvotes, most reputable member of the community, sounds like a pretty big difference to "sixth answer way down the page kind of solves A". It does a better job than this answer.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - The OP has accepted an answer that replicates (in worse detail) what was already on the dupe. Reopening this has made the site subtly worse, not better.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What exactly are the Jedi measuring in the Phantom Menace?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/151659/what-exactly-are-the-jedi-measuring-in-the-phantom-menace)

Comment: VTCing this again as a dupe as per the above comment. This answer is exactly the same just of a far worse quality. It is unfortunate that this is a dupe, but yet, that is how the cookie crumbles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suppose it to be Master Yoda, since Obi-Wan refers to Anakin's midi-chlorian count as "Even Yoda doesn't have a count that high".

Of course, midi-chlorians were a forgettable part of the prequel trilogy (Even more specifically, referenced mostly only in Episode I). Do you see the word used in any part of Force Awakens? It's because JJ Abrams refused to acknowledge the existence of midi-chlorians.

Comment: I'd say this only suggests that Yoda has the highest count of any *currently living Jedi*.

Obi-Wan wouldn't know the midi-chlorian count of any sith, and might not know the midi-chlorian counts of historic Jedi.

Comment: Well since this is the best canon answer we can get, I'm going to go ahead and accept it.

Comment: Yes, for example, we have absolutely no knowledge on how much the Emperor's midi-chlorian count was. Probably would have rivaled Yoda's, as their fight in Episode III was a stale-mate.