# Who were Anakin Skywalker's maternal grandparents?

Tags: star-wars, anakin-skywalker

We of course know Shmi was Anakin's mother and there has been long speculation about his [father](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1630/who-is-anakin-skywalkers-father) (if he had one in the first place), but do we know anything at all about his maternal grandparents and if they were also Force-sensitive?

Answers based on both canon and EU are acceptable.

Comment: I don't think we even knew this in Legends.

Comment: They were Shmi's parents - that what the *maternal* part means :-)

Comment: @RDFozz Thanks for stating the obvious!! Comments like that is the reason I come here everyday :D

Comment: @Loki - Sometimes I read the title of a question, and a comment like this leaps to mind. Sometimes I read the question and move on; sometimes I still feel the need to share. Of course, I'd expect you to understand the need to leave a *mischievous* comment like this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Not known.

The only source of information we have about her parents are from the [Official Star Wars Fact Files](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Official_Star_Wars_Fact_File_(2014)) magazine series, backed up by a nearly identical reference on the original [Star Wars Databank article about Shmi](https://web.archive.org/web/20010722051733/http://www.starwars.com:80/databank/character/shmiskywalker/eu.html).

> *Just as her death was the bleakest of tragedies, Shmi's early life was
> also desperately stark. **When she was very young, her family was
> attacked by pirates and she was separated from her parents.** The trauma
> of this abduction was soon compounded when she was sold into slavery.
> The brief happiness that she had experienced as an infant had been
> snuffed out, and, for the rest of her life, **Shmi had only the vaguest
> memories of those who had brought her into the galaxy.***
>
> <sub><sup>[The Official Star Wars Fact File Part 24](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Official_Star_Wars_Fact_File_Part_24)</sup></sub>

You'll note that this info isn't fully part of the accepted (Disney) Star Wars canon but it seems unlikely that LucasFilm will contradict it in their upcoming films.

Comment: I bet they are Targaryens....

Comment: @Skooba - According to TSR, in a very early version of the script, her name was Shmi Warka. I'm not in the least clear how Lucas was going to tie that up (was Skywarka a nickname, perhaps?).